# very simple scrapy crawler not following links

Tags: python, scrapy

This is a simple `scrapy` spider which crawls yelp.com and fetches data

I've set `Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('.*')),follow=True,callback="parseBusiness")`

To follow links and the callback as parseBusiness

However, Scrapy here, does **not** follow links

This is the specific output (full output here http://pastebin.com/BkuErvMq)

```
2015-07-14 01:06:22 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2015-07-14 01:06:25 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Hotels&find_loc=San+Francisco%2C+CA&ns=1> (referer: None)
2015-07-14 01:06:26 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.yelp.com/biz/ucsf-medical-center-at-mount-zion-san-francisco> (referer: None)
2015-07-14 01:06:26 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-07-14 01:06:26 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
```

This is my code below

```
import sys
import scrapy

from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class Business(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    contactNumber = scrapy.Field()
    address = scrapy.Field()

class YelpSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "yelp"
    allowed_domains = ["www.yelp.com"]
    start_urls = [
    "http://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Hotels&find_loc=San+Francisco%2C+CA&ns=1",
    "http://www.yelp.com/biz/ucsf-medical-center-at-mount-zion-san-francisco"
]

Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=()),follow=True,callback="parseBusiness")

def parseBusiness(self, response):
        business = Business()
        business['name'] = stripchars(response.xpath('//h1[@itemprop="name"]//text()').extract())
        business['contactNumber'] = stripchars(response.xpath('//span[@itemprop="telephone"]//text()').extract())
        business['address'] = stripchars(response.xpath('//li[@class="address"]//text()').extract())
        yield business
```

What am i missing here? to get scrapy to follow all the links

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not setting the [`rules`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider.rules) attribute of your spider:

```
class YelpSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "yelp"
    allowed_domains = ["www.yelp.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Hotels&find_loc=San+Francisco%2C+CA&ns=1",
        "http://www.yelp.com/biz/ucsf-medical-center-at-mount-zion-san-francisco"
    ]

    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('.*')),follow=True,callback="parseBusiness")
    ]
```

Comment: Damn, I spent hours on this, Thanks a lot :D

Comment: @wolfgang I would love to see you check this as correct. :p

Comment: Also note to NOT override the default `parse` function, but use a specialized `parseSomething` function.